# Disable lock screen after screensaver

Tags: lock-screen

I just wiped 16.10 and installed 19.10, and turned off all screen-lock features as this is my personal desktop pc; there's nobody to lock out. The machine is always on but turns the screen off after 5 minutes. When I wake the screen, there is a lock screen thatonly goes away with a mouse trag or the ESC key.

--> How do I get rid of this screen?? I want to wake the screen and see *my screen.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Remove Shield](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/2245/remove-shield/) is a great extension for this.

For shell extensions to work, you need to install Gnome shell extensions: `sudo apt install gnome-shell-extensions chrome-gnome-shell`, log out, and log in again. Then visit the extension webpage and click the slider to "on".

(Once you have that shell extension, check out the [large library of further extensions](https://extensions.gnome.org/).)

[image]

I have installed this in freshly Installed Ubuntu 19.10 and tested.

[image]

Comment: Hi torben... `gnome-shell-extension-prefs` is built in/ out of the box.. Just download the extension and keep it in local or root related directory.. You can then use above command to control..